# aticonfig needs a xorg.conf I have none

Tags: x11, xorg, graphics, ati, amd-graphics

I run a dual seat setup with 2 GPUs.
Lightdm launches the 2 X servers, without any need for a xorg.conf
Now aticonfig, because I use fglrx drivers, tells me :

```
No layout section was found in the file: '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'.
Please run 'aticonfig --initial' first or modify your configuration file manually and run aticonfig again.
aticonfig: parsing the command-line failed.
```

If I run aticonfig --initial it creates a xorg.conf and I can use the aticonfig commands, but at reboot X doesn't launch because of the xorg.conf created which isn't correct for a dual head setup.

what are my options ?

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the xorg.conf created by aticonfig and create a new one with `xorg -configure`.  This should take the default settings X uses when run without a config file and write them to the default config file.

Comment: Can you explain why this should help, please?